# How to select elements with same ID but in different shadow DOMs

Tags: cypress, shadow-dom

So I'm working at a co. as a summer intern and have been tasked with writing tests for their application in cypress.

The application extensively uses shadow DOMs and nested shadow DOMs even. I used the includeShadowDom property true to traverse more easily. But I am facing an issue.

I need to type in 2 input boxes having the same ID and same class but they are in separate shadows. Is there a way I can distinguish between them  i.e First occurrence of element with id= and nth occurrence of element with id=?

I can't share any code because it goes against company policy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have added `includeShadowDom: true` in your cypress config file then you can use the `eq` method to get the respective elements.

E.g. `eq(0)` for first occurrence of the element, `eq(1)` for the second and so on.

So your code should look like this:

```js
cy.get('input').eq(0).type('some text')
```

Comment: Thanks. Idk how i forgot that cy.eq() exists. This worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

First possible solution is to select every input with class = something and loop over each.

```
let words = ['First input', 'second input']
cy.get(`input[class="something"]) // this returns x number of Inputs
  .each( ($el, index) => {
    cy.get($el)
    .type(words[index])
  })
```

Second possible solution is to target the parent element incasing the single input.

```
cy.get('table') //I don't know what is incasing your inputs but lets assume its a table
  .within( () => {
    cy.get(`input[class="something"`] //trying to get this to return 1 element
    .type('words')
  })
```

Without seeing your HTML markup I can't offer up a more exact solutions. Hope this helps. Look up parent() and parentsUntil() cypress commands if you try the second option.

Answer (score 0):

With inputs there's usually some text that allows the user to distinguish them.

Try targeting the input label or placeholder text, finding the input with ["Traversal" commands](https://example.cypress.io/commands/traversal).

```html
<div>
  <label>User name</label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter user name" />
<div>
```

Some basic approaches:

```js
cy.contains('label', 'User name')
  .next()                           // move to next element in the DOM
  .type('something')
```

```js
cy.contains('div', 'User name')     // go to common parent of label and input 
  .find('input')                    // gives just the input inside parent
  .type('something')
```

```js
cy.get('input[placeholder="Enter user name"]')  // use unique placeholder attribute
  .type('something')
```

---

With shadow DOM be aware you can configure it in the test header

```js
it('searches inside all shadow dom roots', {includeShadowDom: true}, () => {
  ...
})
```